# How would the composition of the Venusian atmosphere visually affect the sunrise and sunset there?

Tags: optics, planets

The Venusian atmosphere is according to CalTech's webpage [What is the atmosphere of Venus like?](http://coolcosmos.ipac.caltech.edu/ask/43-What-is-the-atmosphere-of-Venus-like-) is 90 times heavier, than Earth's, containing predominantly carbon dioxide, some nitrogen, sulfuric acid clouds in its atmospheric chemical soup.

What affect would Venus' heavier atmospheric mass and composition have on how the sunset and sunrise would be viewed visually?

Comment: Red sky in the morning, astronaut's warning. Red sky at night, astronaut is probably no longer alive from spending the day on Venus's surface.

Comment: @tpg2114 LOL, that is so very true!

Answer (score 1):

You can't see the sky from Venus surface. In fact, if you look it with a telescope, you will see only clouds. There are very few images of its surface in deed, just retrieved in 1982 by the Venera 13 module. So, I guess the effect is that is cloudy... permanently.

source: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Venus), quote from the first paragraph:

> The Venusian atmosphere supports opaque clouds made of sulfuric acid, making optical Earth-based and orbital observation of the surface impossible.

Comment: Please include some references to support your answer.